# Finding the most efficient way to find the other person

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

As I was yesterday walking across the christmas market trying to find some of my friends I thought of this exercise.

Say you had a square of $n$ length with $n^2$ smaller squares in it ( think 10x10 with 100 squares in it ).
Assume the person, represented by a dot, started randomly on any small square.

Your task is it now, to find the most efficient way ( the best way to find him in the shortest amount of time ).

The rules are:

You must start at one of the edge pieces. If you move one square in any direction ( also diagonally ), he is also allowed to move one square, but can also stay on a square and just wait that turn out.

Also assume you can't see each other, until you are on the same square and can't shout or anything like that.

**First, I'd like to assume the path of the other person is random. And with random I mean, it probably has some kind of pattern ( i.e. standing around, moving some steps, walking a lot, standing again etc. ), but we simply can not predict or know it.**

**Secondly, how would you approach this? I thought maybe there is some kind of probability distribution of where the other person is most likely to be. For example on the edge pieces I'd assume ( intuitively ) that the person is less likely to be there , just because you do not need to pass that square in order to get to another one. So if there was some way to assign each square a certain possibility ( of the other person being there ), that would probably get us a lot closer.**

Comment: I believe this is a random walk problem: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter12.pdf (sorry for just the link. I know enough to recognize the problem but can't thoroughly answer)

Comment: It seems like that is the exact thing I was looking for, thank you very much!